# Qgis layer renaming stays the same

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, layers

I've been developing a plugin for Qgis, but something weird happend while renaming a layer, now whenever i add a layer using a button in my plugin, the layer is renamed with the last name I gave it. I'll explain it using an example.

The plugin creates a buffer around some points and creates a temporary layer to store these buffers. I programmed the buffer_layer to have the name 'buffer_{}'.format(current user) (where current_user is a variable which I tested to be right).
When the layer is loaded however, it will have the name "Buffers". I remember changing the name once to Buffers, and it seems as if Qgis remembers this change and applies it to all layers created by the plugin. 
I can change the name of the layer using right mouse click > rename and rename it to 'testname' and delete it afterwards. If I then add a new buffer layer using the plugin, the layer will have the name 'testname'.

This keeps happening.

I'm on OS X El Capitan, using Qgis 2.12 Lyon.

Added code

```
def calculateBuffer(self):

    proj = QgsProject.instance()
    cur_user = self.SelectUserGroupCombo.currentText()
    # The current user is selected using a drop down menu.
    radius = proj.readNumEntry("SpatialDecisionDockWidget", "radius")[0]
    transittypes = proj.readEntry("SpatialDecisionDockWidget", "transittypes")[0]

    uf.selectFeaturesByExpression(self.getSelectedLayer(),"network in {}".format(transittypes))
    origins = self.getSelectedLayer().selectedFeatures()
    layer = self.getSelectedLayer()


    if origins > 0:
        cutoff_distance = radius
        buffers = {}
        for point in origins:
            geom = point.geometry()
            buffers[point.id()] = geom.buffer(cutoff_distance,12)
        # store the buffer results in temporary layer called "Buffers_[cur_user]"
        buffer_layer = uf.getLegendLayerByName(self.iface, 'Buffers_{}'.format(cur_user))
        # create one if it doesn't exist
        if not buffer_layer:
            attribs = ['id', 'distance', 'network']
            types = [QtCore.QVariant.String, QtCore.QVariant.Double, QtCore.QVariant.String]
            buffer_layer = uf.createTempLayer('Buffers_{}'.format(cur_user),'POLYGON',layer.crs().postgisSrid(), attribs, types)
```

## The layer is renamed here!

```
            buffer_layer.setLayerName('Buffers_{}'.format(cur_user))
            uf.loadTempLayer(buffer_layer)
        # insert buffer polygons
        geoms = [] # geometries in a list
        values = [] #list of lists, consisting of 3 items. E.g. [[0L, 1200, 1],[...

        fld_values = uf.getFieldValues(layer, 'network', True,"network in {}".format(transittypes))[0]
        cnt = 0

        for buffer in buffers.iteritems():
            # each buffer has an id and a geometry
            geoms.append(buffer[1])
            # in the case of values, it expects a list of multiple values in each item - list of lists
            values.append([buffer[0],cutoff_distance, fld_values[cnt]])
            cnt += 1

        uf.insertTempFeatures(buffer_layer, geoms, values)
        self.refreshCanvas(buffer_layer)
        layer.removeSelection()
```

I just thought of a better way to describe this, it is as if qgis overrides the layer name with the name I've given to another when I renamed it. It is as if it remembers the renaming and overwrites the layer name with the 'remembered name'.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  It usually helps us out to take a look at the problematic code to get a better idea of what is going on. From what I understand, you are creating a layer, renaming it (in QGIS or your plugin?) and the next time you run the plugin, you get a buffer layer with the same name as the layer that you just changed the name to?

Comment: Yes, i've done quite the searching for my problem, but haven't found a solution yet.
Yes, i'm creating a layer using the plugin, and assigning a name to it using the plugin (in the code using setLayerName("name")). When the layer is imported in QGIS it gets a different name ("buffers").

Comment: Please add a screen shot of your code to your question. It's difficult to troubleshoot code by guessing.

Comment: What is `uf` defined as?

Comment: uf is a file called utility function, which has some helpful function in it. I could show the code, but that would make things chaotic I guess.. When calling the createTempLayer function with the given name, the variable for that function is indeed correct, so it is probably going wrong somewhere in QGIS...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, apparently the InaSafe plugin is messing with the layer names and overriding it. Checking off the plugin resolved the problem.